# Changing multiple Slider with one button

Tags: javascript, html, slider

Dear stackoverflow users,

I'm working on a project for myself and i run into a js problem.

I'm trying to make a slide with 3 employees on my homepage.

Default it will show image 1, image 2 and image 3.
When i press the back icon, i needs to go to:
Image 4, image 1 and image 2.

My code so far (Only backwards!)

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
let arrowBack = document.querySelector('#arrow-back');
let arrowNext = document.querySelector('#arrow-next');
let currentOne = 0;
let currentTwo = 1;
let currentThree = 2;

// Make employees transparent
function reset(){
    for(let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++){
        sliderImages[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

// Make employee 1 visable
function startSlide(){
    reset();
    sliderImages[0].style.display = 'inline-block';
    sliderImages[1].style.display = 'inline-block';
    sliderImages[2].style.display = 'inline-block';
}

// Show command backwards
function slideBack(){
    reset();
    sliderImages[currentOne - 1].style.display = 'inline-block';
    sliderImages[currentTwo - 1].style.display = 'inline-block';
    sliderImages[currentThree - 1].style.display = 'inline-block';
    currentOne--;
    currentTwo--;
    currentThree--;
}
// Back arrow clicked
arrowBack.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(currentOne === 0){
        currentOne = sliderImages.length;
    } 
    if(currentTwo === 0){
        currentTwo = sliderImages.length;
    }
    if(currentThree === 0){
        currentThree = sliderImages.length;
    }
    slideBack();
})
```

**When i refresh the page i see Image 1, 2 and 3 so that works. But it doesn't go to 4, 1 and 2 when i press #arrow-back.**

I know the structure isn't perfect with my 3x if, but i'm just learning to understand Javascript.

Can any of you guys give me some tips with how i can progress my project?

Thanks a lot.

Great,

Loxiuras

(Be notest that my html works. It will change the images, but it doesn't get the right order.)